# Overlapping of two Date Range

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Given two date ranges, whether the two date ranges overlap?

As an example, suppose we have ranges denoted by DateTime variables `StartDate1` to `EndDate1` and `StartDate2` to `EndDate2`.

eg:

```
(A) StartDate1- 14-08-2014   EndDate1 - 14-08-2015
    StartDate2- 14-08-2012   EndDate2 - 14-08-2013

(B) StartDate1- 14-08-2014   EndDate1 - 14-08-2015
    StartDate2- 14-08-2013   EndDate2 - 14-08-2014

(C) StartDate1- 14-08-2014   EndDate1 - 14-08-2015
    StartDate2- 15-08-2014   EndDate2 - 13-08-2015

(D) StartDate1- 14-08-2014   EndDate1 - 14-08-2015
    StartDate2- 14-08-2015   EndDate2 - 14-08-2016

(E) StartDate1- 14-08-2014   EndDate1 - 14-08-2015
    StartDate2- 15-08-2015   EndDate2 - 15-08-2016
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not Overlapped:

Start1 > End2(after) OR End1 < Start2(before)

So overlapped will be
NOT (Start1 > End2 OR End1 < Start2)

Please note that in order to use "<" or ">" ,you can use Date.getTime() to get the Date of long.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");      
    long Start1 =sdf.parse("14-08-2014").getTime();
    long End1=sdf.parse("14-08-2015").getTime();
    long Start2=sdf.parse("14-08-2012").getTime();
    long End2=sdf.parse("14-08-2013").getTime();
    System.out.println("overlapped :" +!((Start1>End2)||(End1<Start2)));
```

Comment: can you please explain with example? given above date ranges.

Comment: This is only one case, what about the others? further, the requirement was that the ranges will overlap - being inclusive is not required (though it's an option).

Comment: yes can you please explain for all possibility?

Comment: now above example does not include (StartDate1 <= EndDate2) && (StartDate2 <= EndDate1) condition.

Comment: @alfasin , can I have a upvote since I updated my answer and op has accepted it